# In Windows 10, how can I change default keyboard language without changing default display language?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

In the panel `Windows Settings > Time & Language > Region & Language`, when I select second Language as default in order to set a default keyboard language, the default display language is also being changed.

How can I change default language for only keyboard?

Comment: What do you mean by "default display language" and why do you think that this changes it?

Comment: You can see at Region & Language settings, just under the selected Language as "Windows display language"

Comment: I think you misunderstood - there is no "display language". The keyboard is just classified according to its language, that's all.

Comment: Display language is not the keyboards' display language, it is OS display language. Unfortunately keyboard language and OS default display language are being managed in the same setting module that you can easily check: Windows Settings > Time & Language > Region & Language

Comment: Are you not on the latest Windows 10? There isn't such setting : You have Time & Language > Region and Time & Language > Language.